# Is there a way you can determine the minimum value for each independent variable to meet the desired value of a dependent variable in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently working on a decision support system for Licensure Examination Performance using Python but I stumbled with this problem. I want to determine which AREA should an examinee should concentrate on to be able to pass or at least get a Rating of 75.

Suppose I have the following dataframe in Python

```
Age   Sex_M   HS_GWA   Col_GWA   Major Passed_P   Rating
21     1        85        90       1      1         85
23     0        87        88       3      1         75
19     0        91        92       2      1         77
20     0        86        85       0      1         80
20     1        76        86       1      0         65
22     1        88        75       2      0         70
```

I have SUCCESSFULLY implemented the classification (when the target is `Passed_P`) and regression (target variable is `Rating`) algorithms of SKLearn in creating prediction models and used them for prediction.

THE CHALLENGE:

1. What if `HS_GWA` is now the `TARGET` variable while `Rating` becomes constant at  75 and become part of the independent variables. How can we use the independent variables to determine/forecast the minimum value of the DEPENDENT variable?
2. What if `HS_GWA` is now the `TARGET` variable while `Passed_P` becomes constant at  1 and become part of the independent variables. How can we use the independent variables to determine/forecast the minimum value of the DEPENDENT variable?

Comment: I'm finding your question a bit hard to follow. How can `Rating` be both constant and a variable in question 1? Ditto for `Passed_P` in question 2. What is your formula for determining the value of `Rating` and `Passed_P`?

Comment: You say you've implemented something, and ask for ways to improve it, but do not provide a [MCVE] of what you've already got, which makes this pretty hard to answer.

Comment: Also what is the significance of `Col_GWA` and `Major` which seem to be variables but aren't referred to in your question? Please edit all of these points into the question.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The way I read it, OP has implemented some *other* functionality but is stuck on how to begin implementing the functionality that this question is about. I'm not sure OP has anything that could be a MCVE. But I agree that we need more details.

Comment: @JBentley and @ShadowRanger, my apologies for being so unclear in my statements! I just can't express it very well!. For example I used Multiple (Multivariate) Linear Regression in building my Model with ```Y=B0 + B1x1 + B2x2 + . . . +Bpxp +e```. Suppose Y is Rating and now have a default value of 75 and ```x1``` now will be unknown. how can I possibly determine its value using the algorithm or the formula?

Comment: @dJudge I still don't find it particularly clear what you mean and how it relates to the question you posted. In any case this is sounding more like a maths problem rather than a programming problem and is probably better suited to https://math.stackexchange.com/ . Final points, please *edit* clarifications into the question rather than providing them as comments, and note that you cannot use @ to target more than one person per comment.

Comment: On the other hand, if I am mistaken and you do already understand *mathematically* how to achieve what you want but are simply stuck on how to implement it in Python, then please edit the question to make it clearer exactly what you are trying to achieve. Don't talk in terms of Y, B0, B1x1, x1, etc., but rather in terms of the named variables from your example. Specify exactly how each variable relates to the others and what you are trying to achieve.